# how to fill in spaces with following field with awk?

Tags: awk

If I have a file:

```
  1 0 1
1 1   0
0 0   1
```

How can I fill in the space with the number in the following column (if there is one) such that I would obtain:

```
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
```

I've tried:

```
awk '{
         for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {
             if ((($i)==" ") && ($(i+1)!=" ")) {
                 ($i)==($(i+1))
            }
                    print
        }
    }'
```

But I do not get the desired output. I want to do this for every other column, hence the `+=2` in the for loop.

Alternatively, my problem could be solved if there was a way for `awk` to ignore spaces? Is there a way to this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your attempt won't work because awk uses spaces to determine columns.

Comment: Add a `print NF` above the `for` loop to see that in action. Good luck.

Comment: Don't have time to do up an answer, but `gawk` can do fixed-width parsing: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_44.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1 1 1"; OFS="" }
{
    for (i=(NF-2);i>0;i-=2) {
        $i = ($i==" " ? $(i+2) : $i)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
```

Note that this propagates values backwards so even if multiple consecutive values were missing this would fill them in. You didn't say what to do if the last value was missing so this assumes that can't happen or you're OK with the results being blank if it does.

Comment: *@ed* -- would you explicitly invoke **gawk** instead of **awk** in the command line example -- as FIELDWIDTHS is (as stated) a GNU extension?  (I would change, but stackoverflow does not allow one character changes.)

Comment: Nice. Since it may not be obvious: every `1` represents a field width, and fields are assumed to be directly adjacent (there is no concept of a field _separator_ when using `FIELDWIDTHS` - the value of `FS` is ignored).
Thus, the spaces between the values must be described as fields as well, which explains the need for _7_ entries in `FIELDWIDTHS` (4 values + 3 spaces between them).

Comment: @MichaelBack no, I'd call it as is. We don't expect people to invoke GNU sed as gsed or GNU grep as ggrep, etc. so no reason to invokve GNU awk as gawk.

Comment: @ed -- Well... Actually, when I build awk scripts that use GNU extensions at work, I always call out gawk specifically... It would be the same if I used mawk-specific command-line arguments.  Same with sh vs bash.  I respect your position though.

Comment: What if you used an extension that's available in both mawk and gawk but not other awks (a.g. I believe mawk has gensub() these days)? I get where you're coming from but it seems challenging...

Comment: Hm... Well... My version of mawk 1.3.3 actually doesn't have gensub() -- but... I have to admit that I do tend to go overboard. If I found something that was only implemented in a couple modern versions of awk, I would yet avoid the feature or specify one of them explicitly.  For instance, as a last step in my released scripts I even avoid using an RS="\r?\n" -- instead using the admittedly ugly { sub(/\r/,"") }.  Using an extension actually burned me once where gawk on my modern Linux system had a built-in numeric sort and the one on my work's network did not.  Made me late in delivery.

Answer (score 2):

alternative `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/  ([0-9])/\1 \1/'
```

Comment: Kudos for a clever `sed`-only alternative. `sed 's/  \([0-9]\)/\1 \1/'` would make it POSIX-compliant. Note: If there were _multiple_ empty fields  in an input line, you'd need the `g` option, but note that - unlike the `awk` solution attempted by the OP - you wouldn't be able to limit the replacement to _odd_ column indices (every _other_ column).

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of Unix, here's an easy-to-understand combination of `sed` and `awk`:

```
sed 's/^ /@/; s/  / @/g' file | 
  awk '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {
      if ($i=="@") $i = $(i+1)
    }
    print
  }'
```

- `sed 's/^ /@/; s/  / @/g'` fills in `@` for the missing fields in the input:

  - `s/^ /@/` replaces empty *first* fields with `@` (thanks to anchoring the regex to the beginning of the line with `^`)
  - `s/  / @/g'` replaces any other empty fields with `@` (possibly *multiple* ones, due to use of `g`).
- The resulting consistent number of fields  then allows safe use of `awk` with its default algorithm of splitting input into fields by *runs* of whitespace.
- As in the question, every other field (starting with the 1st) is then checked - for `@`, in this case - and, in case of a match, replaced with the value of the respective next field.

Answer (score 1):

The following **sed** script handles both numeric and non-numeric data with multiple digits/characters.  It handles the case of multiple columns being blank by using a *test* to repeat the *substitute* until the *substitute* is no longer successful:

```
sed ':a; s/  \([^ ]\+\)/\1 \1/g; ta'
```

With **awk** a similar solution (perhaps less efficient, as it is similar to the above without using the *g* flag suffix in the *substitute*) is considerably more verbose -- not to mention "tricky" to get right:

```
awk '{ while(match($0, /  [^ ]+/)) { $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) substr($0, RSTART+2, RLENGTH-2) substr($0, RSTART+1, length($0)-RLENGTH+2) } print }'
```

Both implementations retain trailing blanks and print blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

gawk

```
awk -F '  ' 'NF>1&&$2~/^[0-9]|^ [0-9]/{a=+$2;if(length($1)<2){sub("$",a,$1)}else{sub("  "," "a)}}1' file
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Even though this might be the answer, it's a good idea to add a little bit more information to help the OP understand what's going on.

Comment: While unreadable, it does work with `gawk` and `mawk`, but not BSD `awk`, where `+$2` doesn't convert an empty `$2` value to `0`.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for the great responses! I have also coded a more clunky solution, but I have to use `sed` before `awk`:

I first changed the `FS` to `\t` to get:

```
    1   0   1
1   1       0
0   0       1
```

.

```
sed 's/ /x/g' file |

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {
            if ($i=="x") {
                $i=($(i+1))
        }
    }
}1'
```

This gives:

```
1   1   0   1
1   1   0   0
0   0   1   1
```

Comment: If you've managed to modify your input to use a single `\t` (tab) as the field separator and the empty fields are represented by a single _space_, in other words, if your input now looks like this: `$'.\t1\t0\t1\n1\t1\t.\t0\n0\t0\t.\t1'` (`.` represents a space here; doesn't match your revised, tab-based input above, but I assume that's what you _intended_) , then you don't need `sed` at all: simply change `if ($i== "x")` to `if ($i==" ")`, and it should work. You'd only need `sed` if spaces are used to represent both empty field values _and_ separators - as in my answer.

Comment: Also, by changing the format of your input data you've modified the premise of your question and have effectively answered a _different_ question here.
As such, your answer is a distraction.

Comment: Indeed, I shall be more mindful of my initial question next time. Thanks

Comment: I think your original question was an interesting one (I up-voted it), and I think you were given good answers. However, your answer here amounts to a distraction, which is why I down-voted it (I had hoped you would delete it, which is why I waited before down-voting). To help future readers, I suggest you accept the answer that best answers your _original_ question. Generally, I suggest only posting an own answer if it is truly the only one that answers the question.